# Completely disable remote access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, remote-access

I'm on the panic-mode. Today, when navigating to my website, I saw the website was down because of SQL Server timeouts (after an attack with million of login attempts.) ASP.Net pages can't be processed, because SQL Server requests just don't work.

Is there an on/off button for remote access in SQL Server 2008? I saw a lot of vague threads about adding firewall rules. I will never need to remotely access SQL Server, so I don't need to filter access, I just need to limit it to 127.0.0.1. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Server Properties/Connections you can uncheck the

> "Allow remote connections"

box.

Comment: ? => Server Properties/Connection => Allow remote connections.
And where is Server Properties?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Ok, I found this by right clicking on my server in Object Manager, Properties => Connections => Remote Server Connections.

Comment: That's not it ... Allow Remote Connections refers to Server to server running of stored procedures. Unchecking that won't work.

Comment: In my case i had unchecked Server Properties -> Connections -> Allow remote connections to this server but i still was able to connect remotely. The problem was that i had disabled firewall. Once i enabled firewall and unchecked Allow remote connections to this server i was unable to connect to sqlserver2012 remotely.

Answer (score 5):

You can also disable tcp-ip using the configuration manager

Answer (score 4):

1) You should turn off "Allow remote connections" - do this in SQL Server Management Studio (Right Click on server, properties, Connections)

2) Ensure that your firewall is blocked (MSSQL - right click and set it to Block)

Comment: Answers are always welcome, even 2.5 years later. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not to resurrect an old question but I recently came across this need myself.  The remote connections button is server to server communications generally for executing stored procedures and such as mentioned in the previous post.  In lieu of Firewall rules disabling TCP/IP and Named Pipes should prevent external connections if you are running SQL on a laptop for development purposes or a stand alone server and do not want SQL listening to any external ports.

Comment: how do you do this?